# Tasksel vs metapackages

Tags: debian, apt, administration

Some debian applications are installed via `tasksel`, rather than the traditional `apt` tool. What is the benefits/differences between the methods, when we already have the option of `meta-packages`?

Comment: The question has been answered in askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252056/should-i-use-tasksel-tasks-in-apt-or-install-regular-metapackages

Comment: @jhilmer First of all, I'm not an Ubuntu user. Second, it is put in a vague way, not exactly what I'm asking

Comment: The answer in the above link is also valid for Debian. It actually describes the difference and benefits between task and meta-packages.